# html and css3 menu link clickable not work properly

Tags: html, css

Hi all I have simple menu but I don't know how to make link in whole square. Now only working on link click.

```
<ul><li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q5y1sg9v/)

Comment: make link in whole sqaure? do you mean you wish for the menu to be displayed across the whole screen?

Comment: If I click on gray hover anywhere they open a link

Answer (score 2):

Remove the padding from li and add it to the a instead. Also set your a to display:block.

Answer (score 1):

Move your padding from the `<li>` to the `<a>` and set your anchor to `display: block;`

```css
/* add this selector */
li > a {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

Your updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q5y1sg9v/1/

Answer (score 0):

It will open the link when the  element gets clicked. You want it to open the link when the grey box is clicked.

Therefore you have to make the size of  the same size as the grey box. And as the others pointed out you will have to remove the padding from li and give it to a instead (or specify its height and width).